# Swift - Parsing JSON with Combine, URLSession DataTaskPublisher - Strange formatting

Tags: json, swift, combine, urlsession

I'm looking for some guidance here on an issue I'm encountering.  I am polling an API for stock data and instead of getting back an array or formatted JSON I get chunks of it.  Each block of JSON seems to be properly formatted, but the JSON decoders are looking for a properly formatted array.

Prior to using combine I had a different working.  I had to parse the data to remove 4 trailing characters, then I was left with lines of JSON that I could split by newline and then do a forEach loop on to parse.

This was messy but it works.  The issue now is I'm polling streaming data for live quote updating in my UI.  I need to have the JSON chunks read into my class, stored as a variable that will update the UI.  I am not worried about all of that code once I can figure out how to get the data read properly.

I know my app is receiving the data because I see the stats in the debugger for network.  I also test the same API call in a browser and see what data my app is receiving.  I just don't know how to break it up in the combine framework.

I have been working with something like this so far:

```
 return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map { $0.data }
        .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { print("Receive subscription: \($0)") },
                          receiveOutput: { print("Receive output: \($0)") },
                          receiveCompletion: { print("Receive completion: \($0)") },
                          receiveCancel: { print("Receive cancel") },
                          receiveRequest: { print("Receive request: \($0)") })
        
        //.decode(type: CryptoDataContainer.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .decode(type: Quote.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
 }
```

The Quote struct is very basic:

```
struct Quote: Codable {

 public var Symbol: String
 public var Last: Double
 public var Bid: Double
 public var Ask: Double
 public var Close: Double
    }
```

JSON data is posted below, and it streams.  I get a few chunks of it at a time, but if I can split by newline or by everything {.*} to get each JSON chunk and decode individually it would work great.

I'm really looking for Last price and Symbol out of the JSON.  I could even just look for Last and start one individual streaming session for each symbol I need.

I will also need to split these up using a subject to multicast each publisher to multiple subscribers but I wanted to get the basic functionality working before complicating matters.

Update:  From another post I found that the problem is the JSON formatting - The API is returning invalid JSON that is not formatted into an array - it is missing the surrounding [].  This is why it doesn't parse.  Another option may be to simply convert to string, add square brackets around all of the JSON passed down from the server (there is nothing but objects).. and then parse it correctly?  I'm not sure how to do this within a combine map but that seems to be the path forward.

Here’s an example of the map I’m trying to use currently, since the data comes in as json chunks I need to parse them each individually.

```
          .map ({

                let stringRepresentation = String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8)
                let outputJson = stringRepresentation!.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline).map(String.init)
                
                if outputJson.count > 1 {
                    print("DEBUG: outputJson.count > 1 code running..")
                    let formattedOutputJson:String = outputJson.joined(separator: ",")
                    let finalJson:String = "{\"quotes\":[" + formattedOutputJson  + "]}"
                    let data:Data? = finalJson.data(using: .utf8)
                    return data!
                } else {
                    print("DEBUG: outputJson.count = 1 (Else) code running..")
                    let finalJson:String = "{\"quotes\":[" + outputJson[0]  + "]}"
                    let data:Data? = finalJson.data(using: .utf8)
                    return data!
                }
            })
```

Here is a better example of the JSON formatting in chunks I’m talking about:

```
{"heartbeat":4,"timestamp":"\/Date(1622898090819)\/"}
{"heartbeat":5,"timestamp":"\/Date(1622898095819)\/"}
{"heartbeat":6,"timestamp":"\/Date(1622898100819)\/"}
{"heartbeat":7,"timestamp":"\/Date(1622898105819)\/"}
{"heartbeat":8,"timestamp":"\/Date(1622898110819)\/"}
```

If I can even capture the heartbeat number as an Int to use I would be well on my way to getting my code working.  The issue is I get zero data out of this.  I know I’m connected from packet captures and various other tests.  The data is getting to my system, and to the Xcode simulated app, I just don’t think I’m getting it to a point where I can print to the console correctly to display it.  I have been working on that prior to attempting to update the UI directly.

```
{"Description":"E-Mini NASDAQ-100 Jun 2021","PreviousClose":13529.25,"PreviousVolume":552987,"AssetType":"FUTURE","CountryCode":"United States","Halted":false,"Bid":13513.75,"BidSize":3,"Ask":13514.25,"AskSize":1,"Currency":"USD","LastSize":1,"LastVenue":"CME","SymbolRoot":"NQ","Exchange":"CME","LastTradingDate":"2021-06-18","DisplayType":3,"FractionalDisplay":false,"MinPrice":1258200,"PointValue":20,"TradeTime":"2021-06-04T02:40:20.0000000+00:00","MaxPrice":1447600,"MinMove":25,"High52Week":14064,"Open":13531.75,"Low52Week":9591.75,"High":13541.75,"Low":13467.75,"Close":13513.75,"Symbol":"NQM21","Volume":23877,"DailyOpenInterest":231736,"ExpirationDate":"2021-06-18","Last":13513.75,"NameExt":"(D)","DataFeed":"TradeStation","IsDelayed":true,"Restrictions":[null],"VWAP":13499.877658013,"NetChange":-15.50,"NetChangePct":-0.1145665872091948925476282900,"High52WeekTimeStamp":"2021-04-29T00:00:00.0000000+00:00","Low52WeekTimeStamp":"2020-06-11T00:00:00.0000000+00:00","PreviousClosePriceDisplay":"13529.25","BidPriceDisplay":"13513.75","AskPriceDisplay":"13514.25","MinPriceDisplay":"1258200.00","MaxPriceDisplay":"1447600.00","High52WeekPriceDisplay":"14064.00","OpenPriceDisplay":"13531.75","Low52WeekPriceDisplay":"9591.75","HighPriceDisplay":"13541.75","LowPriceDisplay":"13467.75","ClosePriceDisplay":"13513.75","LastPriceDisplay":"13513.75","VWAPDisplay":"13499.88","FirstNoticeDate":"","StrikePrice":0,"TickSizeTier":0,"Underlying":"","StrikePriceDisplay":"0.00"}
{"Last":4188.5,"NameExt":"(D)","DataFeed":"TradeStation","IsDelayed":true,"Restrictions":[null],"VWAP":4184.92506004117,"Description":"E-mini S&P 500 Jun 2021","PreviousClose":4191.25,"PreviousVolume":1384271,"AssetType":"FUTURE","CountryCode":"United States","Halted":false,"Bid":4188.25,"BidSize":39,"Ask":4188.5,"AskSize":23,"Currency":"USD","LastSize":1,"LastVenue":"CME","SymbolRoot":"ES","Exchange":"CME","LastTradingDate":"2021-06-18","DisplayType":3,"FractionalDisplay":false,"MinPrice":3898,"PointValue":50,"TradeTime":"2021-06-04T02:40:10.0000000+00:00","MaxPrice":4484,"MinMove":25,"High52Week":4238.25,"Open":4190.75,"Low52Week":2977.8999,"Hi{"Volume":23880,"TradeTime":"2021-06-04T02:40:23.0000000+00:00","VWAP":13499.879455674,"Symbol":"NQM21"}
{"AskSize":18,"Symbol":"ESM21"}
{"Bid":13514.25,"BidSize":1,"AskSize":1,"BidPriceDisplay":"13514.25","Symbol":"NQM21","VWAP":13499.8800582884,"Volume":23881,"TradeTime":"2021-06-04T02:40:25.0000000+00:00"}
{"VWAP":4184.92521199492,"AskSize":19,"Volume":47807,"TradeTime":"2021-06-04T02:40:27.0000000+00:00","Symbol":"ESM21"}
{"Bid":13514,"BidSize":3,"BidPriceDisplay":"13514.00","Symbol":"NQM21","TradeTime":"2021-06-04T02:40:27.0000000+00:00","Ask":13514.75,"VWAP":13499.8806713352,"Close":13514.5,"Last":13514.5,"Volume":23882,"NetChange":-14.75,"NetChangePct":-0.1090230426668144945211301400,"AskPriceDisplay":"13514.75","ClosePriceDisplay":"13514.50","LastPriceDisplay":"13514.50"}
{"AskSize":18,"Symbol":"ESM21"}
```

Comment: maybe try to embed your code in a DispatchQueue.main.async{ } ?

Comment: You can remove characters and split the string into lines also in Combine using the `map` operator. It’s unclear what a *chunk* really contains.

Comment: I did put the code in the main thread. I see no difference. This seems to be purely a JSON parsing issue. I just hope someone more experienced with swiftUI and combine can help me out with some sample code. I need a template to work off I guess. How can I simply split the returned URLSession data into multiple JSON objects ie { some data } or an array of JSON objects to parse them individually and add to a list etc.

Comment: Vadian, thank you for the direction. Would you be able to post a sample if this to get me started?  I’m new to swiftUI and still thinking in old school non-OOP terms..

Comment: Also not all the JSON chunks will contain data I need. Some are volume updates I don’t care about. I only need to keep the latest price updated to paint candles in the UI.

Comment: Please add an example of an input and expected output.